# Makefile parenthesis handling issue

Tags: bash, makefile

Trying to figure out how to deal with handling ")" in a Makefile and could not find any examples

This is a simple example of the issue I have to deal with which is extracting a list of users in a markdown file

If I do this in bash

```
echo '[ted toe](https://somewhere/users/tedtoe)' | awk -F '[/)]' '{print $5}'
```

I get **tedtoe** as expected

But when I try with this Makefile

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

OWNERS := $(shell echo '[ted toe](https://somewhere/users/tedtoe)' | awk -F '[/)]' '{print $$5}')

owners:
        @echo "The owners are ${OWNERS}"
```

I get the following output

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
The owners are
```

When I try to use ")" as a field separator it will fail
I also tried piping and using `tr -d ')'` but that also fails

Anyone had to deal with parenthesis issues in make files ?

Comment: Not your problem but note that there is a mismatch between `OWNERS` and `OWNERS_1` in your code.

Comment: Fixed - copy and paste typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When parsing your `OWNERS` definition make interprets closing parentheses and considers the closing parenthesis in `'[/)]'` as the one that closes the `$(shell ...)`. Use a make variable instead:

```
CP := )
OWNERS := $(shell echo '[ted toe](https://somewhere/users/tedtoe)' | awk -F '[/$(CP)]' '{print $$5}')
```